# Несогласованное отображение аватара

Tags: дефект, профиль-участника

Пусть имеется [очень старый ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/176787/208074), опубликованный до миграции. В блоке с автором ответа аватара отображается корректно:

> [image: Аватара под ответом: изображение какого-то рыжего существа]

Однако на странице профиля участника отображается стандартная граватаровская заглушка:

> [image: Аватара в профиле: стандартный gravatar-овский графический хэш]

Comment: Забавно, что если отредактировать сообщение, то подхватится граватар. Но после перезагрузки страницы вопроса снова отобразится иконка с чудиком.

Comment: Аватарка в профиле пофиксилась. Но в приложении до сих пор рисуется граватар везде.